# What is considered a good score in Scrabble?

Tags: scrabble, scoring

In Scrabble, what is considered a **good score** for:

- A two player game
- A three player game
- A four player game

In a two player game with my sister, we once got a 236/249 scoring game.

When we played with my brother as well, we got 196/146/98

Are these good scores?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I checked out the recent [NASPA 2016 North American Scrabble Championship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtIL-dRvgGQ&index=12&list=PLXvWVmmqyaqiSwDS0kHQrqbCktAzWtaNL) playlist on Youtube which had ten videos of late round games. I've put the scores of those videos below. Note that competitive Scrabble is only 2 players.

> gibson 585 swift 243
>
> eldar 350 francillon 493
>
> gibson 358 li 311
>
> eldar 480 winter 374
>
> gibson 347 swift 333
>
> eldar 461 winter 460
>
> gibson 397 meller 501
>
> gibson 311 weinstein 449
>
> gibson 397 weinstein 371
>
> meller 438 sherman 436

The lowest score was 243, and it was the only one that was under 300. From this I can surmise that to be a top tier Scrabble player, you should be getting 300 a game on a regular basis. And this is against other very good players who will be attempting to limit your moves. Against regular players you would expect this to be even higher, as they will be less likely to take the doubles and triples.

The important thing, however, isn't to judge yourself based on what is a good or bad score. Rather, are you improving your scores? Are you enjoying the game? Do you know what causes you to get more or less points and how to get better? I think these are far more encouraging and productive questions than reducing yourself to a score comparison.

Comment: Probably the answer that answer most questions in your answer: I absolutely love the game; I even brought two guides!!

Answer (score 1):

I read somewhere LOOOOONG ago, that a decent score in Scrabble is basically around 600-700 with all scores added. So... for 2 players about 300-350 each, for 3 players about 200-230 each, and for 4 players about 150-175 each.

It seems to work OK as a general guide. At least, until you play solo. But then, you'll be loading up 3xLetter scores to get triple Q's and Z's, leaving openings for 3xWord scores, changing tiles every move until you get bingos every time, etc. Stuff you wouldn't do against other players. In this case, single players should be able to score nearly 1000 most games with ease.

Comment: Welcome to Board & Card Games Stack Exchange! This answer would be much better if it included sources. An answer relying on your memory isn't all that authoritative, and will probably attract downvotes. What if I put another answer saying that my memory was that a good score was 300? Having two memories compete against each other isn't very useful for our Q&A website.